# Blockwise Matrix Inversion Stability

Tags: inverse, block-matrices

I have implemented a blockwise matrix inversion. When comparing the blockwise inversion to an inverse of the entire matrix I am seeing deviations from the correct inverse. What should the expectation for blockwise inversion be regarding stability relative to a standard inverse? This causes an issue because multiplying the blockwise results by the original matrix no longer results in the identity.

[Blockwise Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXFn4.png)

Matrix being inverted:

[0.02788,   0.00679,    0.00425,    0.00515

0.00679,    0.14084,    0.00497,    0.00289

0.00425,    0.00497,    0.03055,    0.005

0.00515,    0.00289,    0.005,      0.05109]

Inverse Result:

[37.5317721,    -1.5862237, -4.4296639, -3.2600532,

-1.5862237, 7.2126689,  -0.9269588, -0.1573844,

-4.4296639, -0.9269588, 33.962595,  -2.8248443,

-3.2600532, -0.1573844, -2.8248443, 20.1872839]

Blockwise Inverse Result:

[37.4861497,    -1.5808969, -4.4373105, -3.1229364,

-1.5808969, 7.2152228,  -0.9702984, -0.1593941,

-4.4373105, -0.9702984, 33.9787159, -2.8388331,

-3.1229364, -0.1593941, -2.8388331, 20.1639422]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this block formula won't work very well in general, just because of how many different matrix multiplies and inversions are going on.

As a sample bad case, consider the matrix,
$$ 
X = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & \epsilon & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & \epsilon & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & -\epsilon
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This matrix is invertible as $\epsilon \to 0$, and in this limit the condition number approaches something near $5.3$. So for small epsilon, the original matrix is fairly well conditioned and stable algorithms should be able to give a good solution.

However, The condition number of the condition number of the $(1,1)$ block is $1/\epsilon$ which goes to infinity as $\epsilon \to 0$. This means the inverse of the $(1,1$) block may not even be representable in finite precision arithmetic, and so the block formula will not work well.

Comment: This is very helpful thank you Tyler